# Better approach for Redis Client with multiple subscriber

Tags: go, go-redis

I am new to `golang`. Trying to to use `redis` channel subscription for multiple subscribers. I am using below code in `main()`. Just wanted to know that is it a good approach to use `Redis Client` for multiple subscriber. Is there any better approach? can I create `Redis Client` in another `go` file and initialize that in `main()` method

```
redisClient := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr: os.Getenv("REDIS_ENDPOINT") + ":6379",
    DB:   0,
})

go func() {
    subscriber1 := redisClient.Subscribe("channel1")
    for {
        msg, err := subscriber1.ReceiveMessage()
        go func() {
            gofile1.listenSubscriber1(msg, err) // this method is present in another go file
        }()
    }
}()
go func() {
    subscriber2 := redisClient.Subscribe("channel2")
    for {
        msg, err := subscriber2.ReceiveMessage()
        go func() {
            gofile2.listenSubscriber2(msg, err) // // this method is present in another go file
        }()
    }
}()
```